# Selecting value either from dependent or independent table?

Tags: database, primary-key

I have three tables An Employee Table, a employeeDependents Table, and a Medicare table. The procedure I want to make is either employee or its dependent is provided with medical care. Now I want to put the primary key of either employee or dependent in the table of Medicare.

My question is how  can I get one value from both tables? There is a one to many relationship from employee to employee dependent.

Hope you understand.

Following is the link for a few photos
https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.3811558138512.2159864.1564273389&type=1&l=a2c0c07671&subject=DataBase Question at Stack OverFlow

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you're trying to do?

Comment: yes sure.... i want to select patient id in medicare table... that will be selected from one of two tables. employee or employee dependent

Comment: The patient can be a employee or an employee's dependent. so either employeeid will be entered in patient id or dependent id will be entered in patient id ...

Comment: I would like any body to suggest me a solution... Please Please

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.3811558138512.2159864.1564273389&type=1&l=a2c0c07671&subject=DataBase Question at Stack OverFlow

Comment: you can veiw pics at above link

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing:

1) Employees have an ID (e.g. "employee#"),

2) Employee dependents also have a (unique) ID, as well as a foreign key for the employee#

3) "Medicare" has an ID, and possibly a column indicating whether the patient is an employee or an employee's dependent

Q: Given an employee's medical record from the "medicare" table, can you successfully link back to the employee table?

Q: How exactly are employee dependents "known" in the "medicare" table?

Q: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: No, not a home assignment. Just for learning purposes. I am A gRaduation Student

Employee dependent and Employee are known with the same field like PatientID. that will be filled with one of the IDs from tables. is this even possible.? if not can you give me another solution Please Please.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.3811558138512.2159864.1564273389&type=1&l=a2c0c07671&subject=DataBase Question at Stack OverFlow

Comment: you can view pics at above link

Answer (score 0):

looks like you want to connect the Emp table and EmpDep table with a single table Medicare..
are you assigning any discrete id to the EmpDependents?
if so, then on wat criterion?